# How to connect to SQL Server CE using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ado.net, sql-server-ce

I have a `EntityModel` created from `ADO.NET` that connects to my database. I want to fill a `DataGridview`. For that I'm following this code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FillData();
}

void FillData()
{
    // 1
    // Open connection
    using (SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(
    Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
    {
    c.Open();
    // 2
    // Create new DataAdapter
    using (SqlCeDataAdapter a = new SqlCeDataAdapter(
        "SELECT * FROM Animals", c))
    {
        // 3
        // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        a.Fill(t);
        // 4
        // Render data onto the screen
        dataGridView1.DataSource = t;
    }
    }
}
}
```

This code comes from a Web Page, so I'm trying to adapt it to my `ADO.NET` model. So, as I'm not sure where the `Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString`comes from, I thought it was the connection string used to connect to my database, so, following my `Entity Model`, I wrote this to get the connection string:

```
SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(db.Connection.ConnectionString);
```

Where **db** is my `Entity Model` created like this:

```
private dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
```

But this `db.Connection.ConnectionString` returns this: **"name= dbEntities"**, so I changed it to `db.Connection.DataSource`, that returns this string:

`"C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ProjectName\\MySQLProject\\bin\\Debug\\db.sdf"  string`

But it says that the string format is not adjusted (obviously...). I'm using SQL Server, but I'm not sure how to get that connection :(

The `Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString` says this:

```
        Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString  'System.Windows.Forms.PropertyStore'
```

does not contain a definition for 'Settings' and no extension method 'Settings' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.PropertyStore' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You're not using the full version of SQL Server, you're using compact edition; I've retagged your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message does not mean the connection string is in wrong format! Is says that there are no settings in your project.

Are you sure that you created a respective setting? To edit them, double click the "Properties" entry in your project, then switch to the "Settings" tab. If there's no entry `dbConnectionString`, create one.

Comment: Actually I have that property on my Settings tab. It says exactly this: 
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\db.sdf

Comment: Well, the message says that `Settings` is not available. This has nothing to do with the content not being correct.

Comment: Ok, I could solve that. You were right. It wasn't pointing to the correct namespace, so I added my project namespace before, and it found it :)

Comment: Actually it should work automatically. Did you manipulate the namespaces?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Now I have a different mistake, so I'm gonna try to solve it. And if I can't, I will open a new thread, as it's different to this one. Thanks!!